# How can I request reauthorization for OAuth application on Github?

Tags: github, oauth

For now, I use the scope `?allow_signup=true&login=yourself` to make users reauthorize when they connect their account. But this message would show when they go to that reauthorization page:

`This application has made an unusually high number of requests to access your account. Please reauthorize the application to continue.`

Actually, I am not making a high number of requests, I just want them to reauthorize without revoking their previous access token.

Is there any way I can let them do so without this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this message only appears if the user requests reauthorizes in high frequency. If we can make sure they are not reauthorizing within 1~2 minutes then it should be fine.

Comment: Testing my GtiHub app on my localhost, I'm keeping the token in memory backed storage so when I change a file (in GO), I have to close the application and start the oauth flow again